# Why doesn't "input(...).format(...)" format the prompt?

Tags: python

Given a list of numbers, say:

```
[0,0,2,4]
```

I need to prompt the user to pick a number between the min and max values.

For example, I want to prompt the user with:

```
"Enter a number between 0 and 4: "
```

and have the user must input a number in that range. In order to do that, I need to calculate the min and the max values of the list.

So, if instead the list was `[1,2,4,6,7]`, the prompt should change to:

```
"Enter a number between 1 and 7: "
```

I tried this:

```
input("Enter a number from {0} and {1}: ").format(min(lst),max(lst))
```

...however this does not work. Can anyone help?

Comment: You want the `.format` after the `"` on your string, not the `)` on your call to `input`.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist naw, its more about string formattin

Comment: @RNar You're right, bad reading comprehension on my part.

Answer (score 3):

The `format(...)` must be a method of the string, not of the input statement. Your parentheses are wrong:

```
input( "Enter a number from {0} and {1}: ".format(min(lst),max(lst)) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.format` needs to be *inside* the parenthesis of `input()`. You are attempting to `format` the result of that function, not the string.

```
input("Enter a number from {0} and {1}: ".format(min(lst),max(lst)))
                                         ^ Parenthesis moved from here
```